# Mathematical logic and the induction principle

Tags: logic

**Question:**

Let $U$ be the set of all sequences of positive integers, let $B = \{\langle1,2,3,...\rangle\}$, let $ S (\langle s_1 + 1,s_2,...\rangle) = \langle 1, s_1, s_2,...\rangle$, and let $I(\langle s_1,s_2,...\rangle) = \langle s_1 +1,s2,...\rangle$. Let $C$ be the set generated from $B$ by $S$ and $I$.

(a) Use the induction principle to prove that for every $\langle s_1,s_2, ...\rangle \in C$ there exists an integer $n_0 \ge 2$ such that $s_{n_0 +n} =n+2$ for all $n \ge 0$.

(b) Does the converse to (a) hold? That is, if such an $n_0$ exists, is $\langle s_1, s_2, ...\rangle$ necessarily in $C$?

(c) Is $C$ *freely* generated from $B$ by $S$ and $I$? Justify your answer.

**My attempt:**

For part (c) I am fairly certain that it is freely generated since $S \cap B = \varnothing$. Like wise it seems apparent the $S \cap I = \varnothing$, and $I \cap B = \varnothing$ Also $S$ and $I$ are injective. I won't give the argument for pairwise disjoint unless I am challenged and I think the injectivity is pretty obvious.

My real difficulties are with parts (a) and (b). I think for part (a) I need to use some composition of $S$ and $I$ but I 'm not having much luck with it.

Any advice will be appreciative. Thank you.

Comment: Clarify your definition of $I$.

Comment: @DanielV $I$ is a function that maps $U$ into $U$ by the rule in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (a): To apply induction here, you must show that the unique element $b \in B$ has the described property; and then, if some sequence $c$ has the property, so do $S(c)$ and $I(c)$.

Hint for (b): Try constructing the sequence $\langle s_1,\ldots\rangle$ from $b$ using only $S$ and $I$. Can you do it?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For (b) I suggest proving that if $\sigma=\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, then there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $s_n\le n$ for each $n\ge m$. You can do this by structural induction of the kind that **Mees de Vries** suggests for (a); I’ll do this one and leave that one for you. First, though, I’ll try to explain the intuition behind this approach.

Let $\sigma=\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in U$. The operation $I$ affects only $s_1$. The operation $S$ is a little more complicated, but the important thing right now is that it pushes each term except the first one place further along in the sequence, so that $s_n$ becomes the $(n+1)$-st term of $S(\sigma)$ for $n\ge 2$. That is, if $S(\sigma)=\langle t_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, then $t_n=s_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 3$. This means that if there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $s_n\le s_{n+1}$ for $n\ge m$, then $t_n=s_{n-1}\le s_n$ for $n\ge m+1$, and $t_n\le t_{n+1}$ for $n\ge m+1$. In other words, if $\sigma$ is eventually increasing, so is $S(\sigma)$, and from some point on the $n$-th term of $S(\sigma)$ is less than or equal to the $n$-th term of $\sigma$.

Since the initial sequence $\langle n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is increasing, this means that any sequence $\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ that we can get from it by applying $I$ and $S$ some finite number of times should have a tail that is at or below the corresponding tail of the initial sequence: there should be an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $s_n\le n$ for each $n\ge m$.

This is certainly the case for the initial sequence: it has $s_n=n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Suppose that $\sigma=\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ has this property, and let $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ be such that $s_n\le n$ for each $n\ge m$.

- Let $$I(\sigma)=\langle t_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle=\langle s_1+1,s_2,s_3,\ldots\rangle\;;$$ then $t_n=s_n$ for $n\ge 2$, so $t_n\le n$ for $n\ge\max\{2,m\}$.
- Now suppose that $s_1>1$, and let $$S(\sigma)=\langle t_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle=\langle 1,s_1-1,s_2,s_3,\ldots\rangle\;;$$ then $t_n=s_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 3$, and $s_{n-1}\le n-1$ for $n-1\ge m$, so $t_n\le n$ for $n\ge\max\{3,m+1\}$.

It follows by induction that every sequence in $C$ has this property.

Now find a sequence $\langle s_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in U$ such that there is an integer $n_0\ge 2$ such that $s_{n_0+n}=n+2$ for all $n\ge 0$, but there is no $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $s_n\le n$ for all $n\ge m$. There is at least one very simple example that I’ve left in the spoiler-protected box below in case you get completely stuck.

> $\langle 2,3,4,\ldots\rangle$

Comment: Thank you everyone, I was able to solve it. It turned out that it wasn't as hard as I thought, just took a bit to digest the notations. I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else out.

Comment: @Mike: You're welcome. (That was pretty much my reaction, too: it took a little while to see what was going on, but then it wasn't bad.)